# How to convert hyphenated weights to pounds in csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, append

I have a csv which appears similar to the following:

#### Example data

```
data,data,8-10,data,data
data,data,9-06,data,data
data,data,10-00,data,data
data,data,14-10,data,data
data,data,12-10,data,data
data,data,8-11,data,data
data,data,16-10,data,data
data,data,20-10,data,data
data,data,18-10,data,data
```

I need to perform a calulation with both parts of this weight to turn it into the amount of pounds.

For instance for row 1, I need to output (8 * 14) + 10. However I do not know how to capture both sides of this weight in order to perform said calculation.

#### The desired output:

```
data,data,8-10,data,data,122
data,data,9-06,data,data,132
data,data,10-00,data,data,140
data,data,14-10,data,data,206
data,data,12-10,data,data,178
data,data,8-11,data,data,123
data,data,16-10,data,data,234
data,data,20-10,data,data,290
data,data,18-10,data,data,262
```

Comment: Look into Python's [String.split method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the two quantities? I ask because `(8 * 14) + 10` seems like a strange calculation for converting a weight into pounds.

Comment: Does it? 8 stone 10 lbs represented by 8-10 means is turned to pounds by performing that exact calculation `(8 * 14) + 10 ` :) ?

Comment: He is using stones and pounds, not pounds and ounces. A stone is 14 pounds, so ... etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `csv` library and list comprehensions, you can get the data:

```
import csv

with open('sample.csv') as f:
   c = [r for r in csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')]
    data = [
        item[0] * 14 + item[1] for item in
            [map(int, row[2].split('-', 1)) for row in c]
    ]

    print data
```

Output:

```
[122, 132, 140, 206, 178, 123, 234, 290, 262]
```

The following code, can write all the data into a new for for you:

```
import csv

with open('sample.csv') as f:
    with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as w:
        c = [r for r in csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')]
        data = [
            item[0] * 14 + item[1] for item in
                [map(int, row[2].split('-', 1)) for row in c]
        ]
        for line, d in zip(c, data):
            for l in line:
                w.writelines(str(l) + ',')
            w.writelines(str(d))
            w.writelines('\n')
```

Comment: Apparently this question got marked as off topic, thanks all the same for answering it :) I will be reverse engineering the **** out of this code :)

Answer (score 1):

The `csv` module gives you as string; simply split than column on the dash with [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), and map to `int()`:

```
val1, val2 = map(int, row[2].split('-', 1))
```

Now you have two integer values to calculate with:

```
>>> example = '8-10'
>>> map(int, example.split('-', 1))
[8, 10]
```